# Unrecognized configuration section "microsoft.applicationServer" when trying to build from command line or building a deployment package

Tags: visual-studio, webdeploy, msbuild-4.0

yet I have another problem with building from the command line.
I have a project which i can build in Visual Studio just fine.

But when I try to build a deployment Package in Visual Studio 2012 (publish->Web Deploy Package) I get hit with the error

```
D:\somePath\web.config(905): error ASPCONFIG: unrecognized configuration section "microsoft.applicationServer".
```

But the normal build works fine for that project.

I also run into the same error when I try to build over command line

```
msbuild D:\PathTo\Solution\Project\Project.csproj
    /fl /flp:logfile="D:\buildadventures\Build.log";errorsonly;verbosity=diagnostic
    /t:Build /p:SolutionDir="D:\PathTo\Solution\\";Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCpu
```

And I also get the very same error when trying to build and package from command line (no surprise when even just the build fails)

```
msbuild D:\PathTo\Solution\Project\Project.csproj
    /fl /flp:logfile="D:\buildadventures\Build.log";errorsonly;verbosity=diagnostic
    /t:Build;Package
    /p:SolutionDir="D:\PathTo\Solution\\";Configuration=Release;Platform=AnyCpu;
    PackageLocation="D:\buildadventures\SomeProject.zip";AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false
```

Can anyone help me out with this; what do I have to do to be able to create my deployment package from that?

Comment: Seems I am just missing an installation of WindoWsServerAppFabric here. I'll come back here and comment on that when this solved the issue, but saw it work on a colleague's machine, so chances are good ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so that this is not left open for all eternity:

YES! Installing `WindowsServerAppFabric` solved the issue.